# numpy VisibleDeprecationWarning

Tags: numpy-ndarray

The code below is a coded representation of the matrix used in robotics for coordinate transformations. I don't understand why the warning below is there.

I've seen several posts about this warning, and I know that it's a warning for creating a ragged array sequence, and that it goes away when you write dtype=object. However, my matrix is a 4x4 matrix, and it's not a ragged array sequence, so why am I getting that warning?

numpy version is 1.21.6

**VisibleDeprecationWarning**: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray. T = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)*np.cos(alpha), np.sin(theta)*np.sin(alpha), a*np.cos(theta)],

```
def transforamtion_matrix(link):
    a, alpha, d, theta = link[0], link[1], link[2], link[3]
    T = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)*np.cos(alpha), np.sin(theta)*np.sin(alpha), a*np.cos(theta)],
                  [np.sin(theta),  np.cos(theta)*np.cos(alpha),-np.cos(theta)*np.sin(alpha), a*np.sin(theta)],
                  [            0,                np.sin(alpha),               np.cos(alpha),               d],
                  [            0,                            0,                           0,               1]])
    return T
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made here is that I made the theta variable an array instead of a float or int. Initially, I naturally made theta as float, but as i was pulling values from a list of thetas, it turned into an array.

```
theta = np.random.random_sample([2,1])
link1[3] = theta[0]
link2[3] = theta[1]
```

If I create a transformation matrix after the value is transformed into an array, all the terms with theta become an array, and the terms without theta become an int. Therefore, the elements in numpy have different types, which seems to cause a warning.

So, if you've created a homogeneous matrix and you get the following warning, it's a good idea to check your code for any type corruption.